# Unit testing lambda function with Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, aws-lambda, jestjs

I am new to Jest (so I am still figuring everything out) and I am trying to unit test a lambda function to upload an object to s3. This works fine and the test passes.

```
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event) => {

    // I need to be able to access the value of the "upload" variable 
    // directly from my test
    // Something like...
    // const returnValue = await S3Upload.lambdaHandler(mEvent).upload;

    const upload = await uploadToS3(event);

    // I will need to return other data from this lambda function which 
   // will be passed in the payload of my step function, instead of just 
   // returning "upload" simply so the test can access it. For example;

    return {
    name: name,
    age: age
  };
    
   Instead of...

    return upload;


};

async function uploadToS3(event) {

        let cat = {
            name : 'Bertie',
            breed : 'Cymric',
            color : 'white'
          }
    

        // Write the json version of the cat javascript object to S3
        const params = {
            Bucket: 'myBucket',
            Key: prefix, // file Key
            Body: JSON.stringify(cat),
            ServerSideEncryption: "AES256",
            Tagging: 'myTags'
        };

     
        const key = await s3
            .putObject(params
            )
            .promise();

        return key;
}
```

...and the test

```
const S3Upload = require('../../app');

const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const s3 = new AWS.S3()

let cat1 = {
  name : 'Bertie',
  breed : 'Cymric',
  color : 'white'
}

jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
  const putObjectOutputMock = {
    promise: jest.fn(),
  };
  const putObjectMock = jest.fn(() => putObjectOutputMock);


  const mS3 = {
    putObject: putObjectMock,
  };
  return { S3: jest.fn(() => mS3) };
});

describe('61719699', () => {
  it('should put object', async () => {
    const mS3 = s3;
    const mPutObjectResponse = {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
      },
      body: undefined,
    };
    mS3.putObject().promise.mockResolvedValueOnce(mPutObjectResponse);

    const mEvent = { queryStringParameters: { value: 'test' }, body: { newStuff: 'stuff goes here', eventList: [] } };

    const returnValue = await S3Upload.lambdaHandler(mEvent);
    expect(returnValue).toEqual({
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
      },
      body: undefined,
    });

    expect(mS3.putObject).toBeCalledWith({
      Bucket: 'myBucket',
      Key: 'myKey',
      Body: JSON.stringify(cat1),
      ServerSideEncryption: "AES256",
      Tagging: 'myTags'
    });
  });
});
```

However, I need to return some other data in the handler's return statement, so I want my test to access the result of the "uploadToS3" function directly. I can't figure out how to do this from my test. If anyone could help me out, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What's `S3Upload` class and `s3Service.upl()` method?

Comment: My apologies. I left something in the code from when I was trying to access the uploadToS3 function directly. I have corrected it. It should make more sense now. I think I based my test on another post you answered on here, so thanks for that. :-)

Comment: what do you mean return some other data? Does the mockResolvedValueOnce method work?

Comment: It does work. What I mean that currently I have to return the result of uploadToS3 and use that for my test. It passes but I want to be able to directly access the result of const upload = await uploadToS3(event); and test against that. I don't want to have to return it. The reason being that this lambda function will be a step function task so I will need to return other data to be passed in the payload. I will put some comments in my original post for clarity.

Comment: Do you want to mock the resolved value of `uploadToS3` function rather than `s3.putObject(params).promise()` method?

Comment: No. I want to test the method. I have updated my original question, hopefully that will make my issue clearer. I am sure it's a problem with my not fully understanding the framework yet.